# AS3 Access stage object in singleton returns null

Tags: actionscript-3, null, singleton

I know singletons are sensitive subjects, but I really don't want to hear anything about that, or what you think about this implementation. This question is not about that.

So, I have implemented a singleton using a static var with the instance.

```
private static var instance:SomeClass = new SomeClass();

public static function getInstance():SomeClass {
    return instance;
}
```

`SomeClass` is a class in the library, and inside that one there some instance called `someSymbol`.

For some reason, when I use `SomeClass` as a singleton, every time I want to access `someSymbol` I get `Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference`. But if I implement `SomeClass` with regular instantiation the error disappears.

I've tried accessing `someSymbol` in different ways but I always get the error.

```
someSymbol.rotation = 0;
```

and also

```
var aSymbol = getChildByName("someSymbol");
aSymbol.rotation = 0;
```

and also

```
trace(someSymbol); // null
trace(this['someSymbol']); // null
trace(SomeClass.instance.someSymbol); // throws error
```

So why do I get `null` when using this singleton implementation, and not when instantiating the class as usual?

Edit:

Thanks to @Marty Wallace answer, I changed my singleton implementation and now it works.

So, instead of instantiating the instance this way:

```
private static var instance:SomeClass = new SomeClass();
```

I instead instantiate it the first time `getInstance()` is called, as @Marty does it.

I don't know exactly what is going on behind the curtains, but it seems as if `SomeClass` wasn't fully exported when instantiating before the document class is running.

Comment: This is an interesting question - I'll check it out now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is working fine for me:

```
public class Singleton
{

    private static var _instance:TestClip;


    public static function get instance():TestClip
    {
        if(_instance === null) _instance = new TestClip();
        return _instance;
    }

}
```

And `TestClip` has an inner MovieClip with the instance name `inner`:

```
trace(Singleton.instance.inner); // [object MovieClip]
```

Do you have any luck if you make a class for `SomeClass` and make a getter for `someSymbol` like this?

```
public function get someSymbol():MovieClip
{
    return this["someSymbol"];
}
```

Comment: @Pier Flash. I'm still not getting your error. In fact I never get `null`, just undefined.

Comment: Flash CS6? I'm using Flash CC and I'm beginning to suspect this is another bug in CC...

Comment: @Pier CS5.5, but I can't imagine that the behaviour would differ between 5.5 and 6.

Comment: @Pier What happens if you make a getter in your class for `someSymbol` and just return a new standard MovieClip instance?

Comment: It's even stranger... that returns an error on the getter definition line `1021: Duplicate function definition`.

Comment: @Pier Hmm yeah sounds pretty buggy to me.. Not really sure what to suggest from here.

Comment: Sorry about the last comment (I hadn't saved an .as). The error persists... and when using the getter I get a duplicate definiton error.

Comment: @Pier Is there a chance of you zipping up the files and sending them over for me to look at? (Not sure how Flash CC works).

Comment: I could make a reduced version of the project, but it would be in Flash CC... and you couldn't open it with CS5.5.

I suppose it would be easier to just duplicate the project in CS6 (which I also have installed) and see what happens. If it works it's a bug in CC...

Comment: Exactly the same behaviour in CS6... I'm completely puzzled. Thanks for your time @Marty, I'll see how to solve this in another way.